# Is there a type of encryption with easy inmplementation in php that meets this criteria?

Tags: php, encryption

I am coding a solution that requires data to be encrypted in to strings of the same length.

The solution needs to meet this criteria:

- Easy implementation in PHP
- Creates same length output regardless of length(similar to MD5) edit: Time to redefine. Creates the same output length from the same input length.
- Can encrypt a string(disregard this)
- Public key encryption is fine, I will keep the key stored privately no matter what, and it won't be distributed.

Basically I just need some type of encryption that will handle this, MD5 would be the answer but I need to decrypt everything too.

I have spent hours looking this up. I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: That's because it's impossible to resolve points 2 and 3.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should redefine. Two inputs that are the same length create the same output length. And I am fine if the string needs to be encrypted to binary first.

Comment: why such a requirement for the "same length"?

Comment: It is because I want to keep them all the same for consistencies sake because the output is going to be similar to a product key in use.

Comment: what does same length do with consistencies sake?

Answer (score 2):

> Can encrypt a string

If it's to be called encryption, it must be reversible, therefore..

> Creates same length output regardless of length(similar to MD5)

is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look the [MCrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) extension for php, there are plenty of cypher availables and already implemented.
However i don't think they can meet your second criteria (because they add padding if necessary).

Or you can try to implement a [CTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing) algorithm which will allow you to meet your second criteria. However CTS brings complexity.
There is already a post on CTS in SO: [Cipher Text Stealing Algorithms - Which one is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407842/cipher-text-stealing-algorithms-which-one-is-correct)

Edit: If you can't use Mcrypt and are ok with cypher that use block to encrypt (thus padd the original data if necessary), you can use this implementation of the AES cypher: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes-php.html
Regards

Comment: Thanks, I believe this should work too. It in fact may even might be a little bit better. The good thing is I have the next month to write the PHP for the encyption that I am going to be doing. I will read up on this tonight and then crash in the morning.